# Apple - Provisioning profile + Push Notifications

Tags: xcode, push-notification, provisioning-profile

I followed the guide on Parse.com on how to create a certificate and prepare a provisioning account to accept Push Notifications. When i go to Preferences/Accounts :
It shows on the bottom, but when i try to choose it from the Build Settings Tab, it doesn't show, and i always get this error : `"no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application"`

[image: Screenshot]

I tried this from scratch several times, using several Xcode & parse Apps, Please help me.

Appdelegate code :

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        Parse.setApplicationId("MyAppId", clientKey: "MyAppClientKey")

        var notificationType: UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound

        var settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationType, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

        var currentInstallation: PFInstallation = PFInstallation()
        currentInstallation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
        currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {

        println(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the device onto the Development Provisioning Profile, then download and installed it? I got that same error until the device was added.